# Trust Question with IHT (UK)

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, inheritance, trusts

This is a fictional scenario but I'm trying to get my head around it. Say if we had the following.

James had a discretionary trust with £600,000 in cash and shares on March 2011. James agreed to pay the IHT arising. He had a previous chargeable transfer  of £149,000 in June 2007.

In September 2020, the Trustees distributed £125,000 to a beneficiary (the Trustees paid any IHT). The trust property was worth £900,000 in March 2021.

I want to find the IHT due on the distribution in September 2020 and the 10-year anniversary charge in March 2021.

The IHT charge will be ZERO as the total charges are £274,000, less than NIL rate band so no IHT due.

However not sure if I have worked the 10 year charge right.

I assume we do:

```
£900,000 - £274,000 = £626,000 x 6% = £37,560.
```

Although this does not encompass the trustee paying the tax so would you do?:

```
£37,560*20/80=£9,462.50?
```

Thanks